# Why do people make a huge pause before making even a simple checkmate?

Tags: checkmate, cheating

Are they already so happy about the victory or is this behavior of the cheat program? I don’t believe in what they think over the simplest move.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what other players do. I pause because I

- have time on the clock,
- am (at Lichess classical 1590) not a strong player,
- am not a quick calculator,
- have insufficiently memorized some basic mating patterns, and
- do not wish to blunder.

If your opponent still has time left on his or her clock, do you know a reason he or she should not pause?

When an annoyed online opponent of mine (usually an opponent who is losing) demands that I move faster, I merely

- kill the chat so that I can finish the game in peace and
- block the opponent so that he or she need suffer no further annoyance in connection with me during future games.

Meanwhile, if my opponent prefers not to wait while I use the time on my clock to think, then he or she can always resign.

Admittedly, it is indeed slightly impolite to run one's clock down *for the mere sake of running it down,* but I seem to encounter this peculiar form of impoliteness in no more than five percent of all games. When I do encounter it, I relax, stretch my legs, review the game's earlier moves, read a nonchess book, catch up on the news, do chores, attend to children, etc., and don't let the play bother me much. Otherwise, the time on a player's clock is the player's to use as he or she sees fit. A player owes no explanation of a thinking pause, not even before delivering mate.

A sportsman should probably not presume to instruct an opponent regarding how fast to think.

As to whether cheating is occurring, I have no idea. I doubt that it happens much in my games. It isn't happening on my end; and on the other end, who knows? Insofar as cheaters are not especially targeting me and insofar as the online platform on which one plays makes a reasonable effort to detect and deter cheating, I have not found it profitable to worry too much about that.